# Nginx location try_files not working with $_GET param

Tags: nginx, parameters, query-string

I have the following configuration in nginx:

```
location /abc {
    alias  /home/abc/interface/wui/public/;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri /abc/index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/<name>/web/ip_filtering/abc_web.conf;

    location ~ /abc/(.*\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/abc/abc-web.socket;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/abc/interface/wui/public/index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/abc/abc_fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

All works fine except URL with $_GET parameters like

```
/abc/tree/export/Act/export/?TreeIds[]=2
```

The code goes to the correct controller and action but no parameter **TreeIds** is found.

The issue is with the **try_files** directive.

We tried the following

```
try_files $uri /abc/index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/<name>/web/ip_filtering/abc_web.conf;

    location ~ /abc/(.*\.php)$(.*)$ {
```

and

```
try_files $uri /abc/index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/abc/web/ip_filtering/abc_web.conf;

    location ~ /abc/(.*\.php)$$is_args$args {
```

And other combination of the above. We cannot make the regex match the try_files **/abc/index.php$is_args$args**